# top batch to dump CPU usage for all CPUs

Tags: top, batch

I am looking for a command that I can run in a batch mode and report back to a monitoring server. I'd like a CPU usage across all CPUs (the equivalent of running top in interactive mode and then hitting the '1' key). It should work on Mac, Ubuntu and Centos.

I've tried a few commands such as from this post ([How do I get an output from Linux Top in Batch Mode on every iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492362/how-do-i-get-an-output-from-linux-top-in-batch-mode-on-every-iteration))

```
top -p 310-b -n2 -d 1 | grep -w 310
```

But it doesn't work on a mac:

```
invalid option or syntax: -p
```

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: You would need an abstraction layer. Use Nagios.

Answer (score 0):

However if I prefer to you use a monitoring such as `Nagios`, But becuae you asked for batch mode, consider the following commands;

- `vmstat`
- `sar`
- `free`
- `iostat`
- `pidstat`
- `mpstat`

Enjoy them...!